# How to sign a PDF with PIV using a Yubikey in UWP C# app?

Tags: c#, yubico, yubikey, yubihsm

I'm trying to implement YubiKey HSM using PIV for my windows app (UWP Xamarin C# .NET). I found a couple of ways to communicate with my YubiKey FIPS but it didn't worked out well. As suggested in the Yubico site, I tried with PKCS11 with Pkcs11Interop nuget package.

https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/YKCS11/

I tried out the example given in the Pkcs11Interop GitHub (https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/master/doc/GETTING_STARTED.md).

But it throws "Method C_GetSlotList returned CKR_DEVICE_ERROR" this error when I tried running.

Please help me to sort out this issue or provide me with a library/code sample which may help me in this implementation.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just wanna mention that I'm facing the same error when writing a program which uses the PKCS11 interface.

Comment: Update: With strace I got some more details - in my case from pcsc-daemon. Actually it was a simple permission issue. Running my program with root permissions did not show the issue.